# Creating a dynamic div with a triangle pointing down

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to build a Div that has a triangle pointing down like an arrow.
I was successful in using a `div:after` and building a triangle from that div.

The problem is that once I move the screen around the new triangle, it does not take the new width of the original triangle into account. I would have to use the width as a parameter for the border CSS property.

Is there another way I could accomplish this? I have created a little image that explains what exactly is the number I am looking for.

[image]

Comment: I would suggest using an `SVG` background image (you can even embed it as a `url()`) and then stretching it to the width and height of the box, stretching the box as desired. You won't accomplish this with `border`.

Comment: css does not support percentage as border-width. But that would be what you need. the comment before mine is pointing you in the right direction.

Comment: How's the parent div's size set? Borders don't accept percentages, but if the parent div is a certain percentage of the viewport, you could use vw.

Answer (score 1):

Here is old-fashioned-jquery solution:

https://jsfiddle.net/zLb4a08e/2/

JS + jQuery:

```
function recalcBorders() {
   var parentWidth = $(".parent").width();
   $('.triangle').css({
      "border-top" : parentWidth / 2 + "px solid blue",
      "border-left" : parentWidth / 2 + "px solid transparent",
      "border-right": parentWidth / 2 + "px solid transparent"
    });
}

$(window).on('resize', function(){
   recalcBorders();
});

$(function(){
  recalcBorders();
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="parent">
</div>

<div class="triangle">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.parent {
  width: 100%;
  background: green;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
}

.triangle {
  position: absolute;
}
```